# JQUERY is not working on (onchange) function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, mysqli

I am Creating a dependency drop downs but,

When I pass Id from one function to another its not Working
here is some sample of code

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="all_category">
        <option>select a category</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        category();
         function category(){
            $.ajax({
            url : "action.php",
            method : "POST",
            data : {category:1},
            success : function(data){
                $("#all_category").html(data)
            }
        })
    }
    $("#all_category").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var xyz = $("#all_category option:selected").val();
        console.log("hello"+xyz)
    })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is to take data from `API`,

And when I print the ID from first dropdown,

It just print the massage before My Id Variable in console.log

```
<?php
include "../db.php";
if (isset($_POST["category"])) {
    $get_assign_course = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $run_p_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_assign_course);
    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($run_p_cats)) {
        $cat_id  = $rows['cat_id '];
        $cat_title = $rows['cat_title'];
        echo "<option value='$cat_id '>$cat_title</option>
        ";}}
?>
```

This is my `API`
help?

Comment: What does `category();` in your Javascript do? Where does that go? Do you see all the categories initially and you are having problems when the user selects one?

Comment: yes initially I am having my all category with the code in my API and what I want is to print the Id of that category in console.log which I have selected

Comment: did you try `$("#all_category option:selected").text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:
$("#all_category").change(function
Into this:

```
$("#all_category").on('change',function
```

Or try this:

```
$(document).on('change','#all_category',function(){
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I have tried this but it dosent work ```$(document).on('change','#all_category',function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var xyz = $("#all_category option:selected").val();
        console.log("hello"+xyz)
          
        })```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.html()` in jQuery it will destroy any of the binding that has already occurred on the events. That's because `html` removes the DOM tree and reinitializes it with the data.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {category: 1},
      success: function (data) {
        $("#all_category").html(data);
        $("#all_category").on('change', function (evt) {
          console.log($(this).val())
        })
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

To fix this issue you need to rebind after the `.html()` call is made.